# Android Studio Bar Code Scanner App. Scanning Via Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, barcode-scanner, onactivityresult

I have an android app that has a very simple layout. A button (scan_barcode1) that is followed by an edittext (scan_content) and another button (scan_barcode2) followed by another editext (scan_content2).

```
     <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanner"
    android:id="@+id/scan_barcode1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="openScanner1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_barcode1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/serial_number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner7"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner7" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanner"
    android:id="@+id/scan_barcode2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="openScanner2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/scan_content2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_barcode2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/serial_number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scan_content" />
```

WHAT I WANT MY APP TO DO: Upon pressing a button, the scan functionality will open, scan the barcode and place the serial number in the edittext below it. For example if you press scan_barcode1 the serial number will be placed in scan_content and if scan_barcode2 is pressed the serial number will appear in scan_content2.

WHAT MY APP DOES: Upon pressing a button, the scan functionality will open, scan the bar code is placed in both editext in the activity. For example, if I press scan_barcode1, the serial number is placed in scan_content and scan_content2.

The following is the code for the intents that call the bar code scanner. I am using the zxing library fyi.

```
    //This method opens the barcode scanner when scan_barcode1 button is pressed

    public void openScanner1 (View view) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator (this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}



    //This method opens the bar code scanner when scan_barcode2 is pressed

    public void openScanner2 (View view) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

I initialize the two editText as contentTxt and contentTxt2

```
     contentTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    contentTxt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_content2);
```

I then begin the OnActivityResult Method which retrieves the edittext and is supposed to place it in the correct edittext (it doesnt)

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    //Places barcode in the scan_content editext

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
    }

    //places bar code in the scan_content2 edittext
    if (scanningResult !=null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt2.setText(scanContent);
    }


    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Instead the barcodes just replicate across both of the edittext. I have been stuck on this problem for some time and Im desperate for a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated!

So I have updated my code but now instead of retrieving the barcode at all i get null as the result and my toast message pops up. Anyone know what going on? This happens no matter what button I press.

```
     private int scanFieldPosition = 0;

public void openScanner1 (View view) {
    scanFieldPosition = 1;
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator (this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

}

public void openScanner2 (View view) {
    scanFieldPosition = 2;
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null && scanFieldPosition == 1) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
    }

    if (scanningResult !=null && scanFieldPosition == 2) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt2.setText(scanContent);
    }


    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

The problem was that I didnt have the variable static. I still get the toast message but my barcode it placed in the right edittext which is strange. Anyways, my app works now thanks to all your help!

```
    private static int scanFieldPosition = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `static` flag set for this, and assign `1` when to it when button1 is pressed and assign `2` to it when button2 is pressed. Then you could check for the flag in your `onActivityResult()`. You could do something like this:

```
public static int editTextNumber = 0;


public void openScanner1 (View view) {
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator (this);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
editTextNumber  = 1;
}


public void openScanner2 (View view) {
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
editTextNumber = 2;
}
```

And then in your `onActivityResult()`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

//Places barcode in the scan_content editext


Log.e("editTextNumber",""+ editTextNumber ); // check whats value here
if (scanningResult != null && editTextNumber == 1) { // checking for flag here
    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
    contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
}

//places bar code in the scan_content2 edittext
else if (scanningResult !=null && editTextNumber == 2) {  // checking for flag also
    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
    contentTxt2.setText(scanContent);
}


else{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
   }

}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help. I feel like we are on the right track but when I scan the barcode, I get null as the result and the toast message pops up "No scan data recieved!" Any Idea what went wrong?

Comment: @Gabriel is it always null?

Comment: I get the toast message all the time as if it is null, but the scan data is still recieved.... pretty wierd

Comment: which toast message `No scan data received!"` this one ?

Comment: @Gabriel, I have logged the value of editTextNumber variable, run this and tell me whats the value, or Toast the value if you're testing on device.

Answer (score 1):

If `scanningResult` is not null (in other words, if the condition of your `if` clause is true), you're setting the text for both EditTexts. 
You need to save some kind of information identifying the `EditText` to be filled when creating scan Intent, and retrieve that in your `onActivityResult`, for example :

```
private int scanFieldPosition = 0;

public void openScanner1 (View view) {
    scanFieldPosition = 1;
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator (this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}


public void openScanner2 (View view) {
    scanFieldPosition = 2;
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Then check `scanFieldPosition` in `onActivityResult` to know which `EditText` to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your construction of the scan intent within IntentIntegrator but I'm guessing you're using the same requestCode.

Change your construction of the scan intent to have different requestCode's (probably by passing a value into the IntentIntegrator in addition to the context) and then when onActivityResult is called you will be able to check this to know which scan button was pressed and populate the relevant EditText.

It's what the requestCode was designed for rather than holding a variable that could lead to state issues.